# Stabilizer of a hyperpalne and cocompactness

Tags: geometric-group-theory

If $G$ acts cocompactly on a CAT($0$) cube complex $X$, I wonder why every hyperplane is acted on cocompactly by its stabilizer?

I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make up some terminology for "mid-cubes" (I cannot remember the standard terminology).

And then I'm going to list some simple facts.

- Each $n$-cube $C \subset X$ has exactly $n$ "mid-cubes", each of dimension $n-1$.
- For each hyperplane $H$, the intersection $C \cap H$ is either empty or a mid-cube of $C$. Furthermore, $H$ is a union of mid-cubes.
- For each $n$-cube $C$ and each mid-cube $M$, there exists a unique hyperplane $H$ such that $m=C \cap H$.
- Since $G$ acts cocompactly on $X$, the set of $G$-orbits of cubes is finite.
- And since each cube has finitely many mid-cubes, the set of $G$-orbits of mid-cubes is also finite.

Now let $H$ be a hyperplane. It is a union of mid-cubes. From the list of properties above, it follows that there exists a finite set of mid-cubes $M_1,...,M_k$ in $H$ having the final property:

- For each mid-cube $M \subset H$ there exists a unique $i \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$ and an element $g \in G$ such that $g \cdot M_i = M$. Furthermore, $g(H)=H$ (because $H$ is the unique hyperplane containing $M$ and $H$ is also the unique hyperplane containing $M_i$).

It follows that the $\text{Stab}(H)$-orbit of the compact set $M_1 \cup \cdots \cup M_k$ is equal to $H$. And that is the definition of the statement "$\text{Stab}(H)$ acts cocompactly on $H$".

Comment: Do we require each $g\in G$ maps a cube to a cube? And why $G$ acts cocompactly on $X$, the set of $G$-orbits of cubes is finite?

Comment: The say that a group acts on a mathematical objects means, implicitly, that it preserves all the structure of that object. So yes, for a group to act on a cube complex means that it takes cubes to cubes. For your second question, I'm sure you can prove that compact set can intersect only finitely many cubes.

Comment: Can I say $g$ is an isometry thus it maps a hyperplane to a hyperplane. Or can I just say the action preserves the structure of the object?

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ is a 2-dimensional cube complex, whose cubes are of the form $[m-1,m] \times [n-1,n]$ for all integers $n \in \mathbb Z$. But an isometry of $\mathbb R^2$ need not map a hyperplane to a hyperplane. In fact, the isometry $f(x,y) = (x + \sqrt{2},y + \sqrt{2})$ does not map any hyperplane to a hyperplane.

Comment: As said in my earlier comment, a group action on a cube complex means that each group element $g$ takes cubes to cubes. To be more explicit: $g$ takes each vertex ($0$-cube) of the cube complex to another vertex; $g$ takes each edge ($1$-cube) of the cube complex to another edge; $g$ takes each square ($2$-cube) of the cube complex to another square; and in general $g$ takes each $n$-cube to another $n$-cube, for each integer $n$. That's what it means for the group to act on the cube complex, and that's the hypothesis which implies that the group action maps hyperplanes to hyperplanes.